# Extract values from data frame using data frame of indexes - R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data frame of useful information:

```
X = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Y = c(5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4)
Z = c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)

df <- data.frame(X, Y, Z)
```

And a data frame of row and column positions:

```
row <- c(6,2,5)
column <- c(1,2,3)


pos <- data.frame(row, column)
```

I would like to use some function (`fun`) that uses the column and row positions in `pos` to return the values in `df` occupying those positions, e.g.

```
fun(df, pos$row, pos$column)
[1] 6 4 15
```

I thought I could do it like this, but to no avail

```
df[c(pos$row),c(pos$col)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The row/column index works as a `matrix`, so we convert to the 'pos' to a `matrix` and use that as row/column index for extracting the values.

```
df[as.matrix(pos)]
```

or otherwise, `cbind` the columns of 'pos' as `cbind` of `vector`s returns a `matrix`

```
df[cbind(pos$row, pos$column)]
```

---

This can be converted to a function

```
fExtract <- function(dat, indexDat){
                 dat[as.matrix(indexDat)]
            }
fExtract(df, pos)
#[1]  6  4 15
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with a function inside a call to `sapply`, working down the rows of `pos`:

```
sapply(seq(nrow(pos)), function(i) df[pos$row[i], pos$column[i]])
[1]  6  4 15
```